# STM32F107 Read Out Protection by Code HAL

Tags: c, stm32, stm32cubeide

i want to enable the normal Read Out Protection, currently I do it in the ST Link Utility but better will be in code. I found some old snippets which are for the old Std Lib, not for HAL:

```
 if (FLASH_OB_GetRDP() != SET) {

  FLASH_OB_Unlock();

  FLASH_OB_RDPConfig(OB_RDP_Level_1);

  // Start the Option Bytes programming process
  if (FLASH_OB_Launch() != FLASH_COMPLETE) {
    // User can add here some code to deal with this error
  }

  FLASH_OB_Lock();
}
```

Does anybody have the right Code which is working for HAL Lib?

Thanks!

Comment: You should check out ST's own firmware examples. There is an [application note](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/dm00209695-stm32cube-firmware-examples-for-stm32f1-series-stmicroelectronics.pdf) listing all examples. In this PDF, I see an example for STM32F103 (quite similar to your STM32F107), "FLASH_Write Protection" (page 7/31). The example is most likely written in C, and it shouldn't be a big effort to port it from NUCLEO-F103RB to your target.

Comment: But this is for Write not for read out.

Comment: You may be right - I didn't inspect the code example. Usually, these examples are meant to be a starting point for adaption. Maybe you can modify some detail to achieve what you need?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use to unlock OB

```
 HAL_FLASH_OB_Unlock()
```

http://www.disca.upv.es/aperles/arm_cortex_m3/llibre/st/STM32F439xx_User_Manual/group__flash__exported__functions__group2.html

and to program it.

```
  HAL_FLASHEx_OBProgram(pointer_to_your_settings);
```

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwiP0KWy-tDoAhXjoFwKHYyxCSEQFjAAegQIBhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.st.com%2Fresource%2Fen%2Fuser_manual%2Fdm00154093-description-of-stm32f1-hal-and-low-layer-drivers-stmicroelectronics.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2zqwDJaPHMqdmT1MlIESNw

Comment: Tried that Code: 

`HAL_FLASH_OB_Unlock();
 HAL_FLASHEx_OBProgram(OB_RDP_LEVEL_1);
 HAL_FLASH_OB_Launch();
 HAL_FLASH_OB_Lock();`

But I can still read out the Flash with the ST Link Utility

Answer (score 1):

```
  HAL_FLASH_Unlock();
  HAL_FLASH_OB_Unlock();
  pOBInit_for_readprot.OptionType = OPTIONBYTE_RDP;
  pOBInit_for_readprot.RDPLevel = OB_RDP_LEVEL_1;
  HAL_FLASHEx_OBProgram(&pOBInit_for_readprot);
  HAL_FLASH_OB_Launch();
  HAL_FLASH_OB_Lock();
  HAL_FLASH_Lock();
```

There is a working procedure to programm RDP.
Prooved by my stm32f4 project.

Comment: FLASH_OBProgramInitTypeDef pOBInit_for_readprot; structure for read/write